# Stop placeholders being inserted into code

Tags: jquery, forms, field

I have this jQuery that edits code in a textarea, from content inserted into fields. You can see it live [here](http://pholiooo.com). The problem is that the placeholders get inserted into the code if the user doesn't put something into one of the fields. Instead, I want the regular identifiers to stay there instead of them being replaced if the field is left empty.

Here's the jQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var basicHtml = ($('.code').html()).replace(/&lt;/g,'<').replace(/&gt;/g,'>');

    $('.code').val(basicHtml);

    $('form').on('submit',function() {
        var content = basicHtml;
        content = content.replace(/%name%/g, ($('#name').val()||$('#name').attr('placeholder')));
        content = content.replace(/%slogan%/g, ($('#slogan').val()||$('#slogan').attr('placeholder')));
        content = content.replace(/%description%/g, ($('#description').val()||$('#description').attr('placeholder')));
        content = content.replace(/%bio%/g, ($('#bio').val()||$('#bio').attr('placeholder')));
        content = content.replace(/%analytics%/g, ($('#analytics').val()||$('#analytics').attr('placeholder')));
        content = content.replace(/%favicon%/g, ($('#favicon').val()||$('#favicon').attr('placeholder')));
        var final = content.replace(/%dribbble_username%/g, ($('#dribbble').val()||$('#dribbble').attr('placeholder')));
        $('.code').val(final);

        return false;
    }).on('reset',function(){
        $('form textarea:not(.code),form input').val();
        $('.code').val(basicHtml);
    });

});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically setting it by reading the placeholder attribute. Fixed code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var basicHtml = ($('.code').html()).replace(/&lt;/g,'<').replace(/&gt;/g,'>');

    $('.code').val(basicHtml);

    $('form').on('submit',function() {
        var content = basicHtml;
        content = content.replace(/%name%/g, ($('#name').val()));
        content = content.replace(/%slogan%/g, ($('#slogan').val()));
        content = content.replace(/%description%/g, ($('#description').val()));
        content = content.replace(/%bio%/g, ($('#bio').val()));
        content = content.replace(/%analytics%/g, ($('#analytics').val()));
        content = content.replace(/%favicon%/g, ($('#favicon').val()));
        var final = content.replace(/%dribbble_username%/g, ($('#dribbble').val()));
        $('.code').val(final);

        return false;
    }).on('reset',function(){
        $('form textarea:not(.code),form input').val();
        $('.code').val(basicHtml);
    });

});
```